# Portable erlang

Tags: erlang, software-distribution, production-environment

Is there a recommended way to "bootstrap" an Erlang distribution? I would like to run erlang on the bunch of machines where I do not have root elevation nor development tool-set (no compilers etc ...) . My thinking was to pre-package (on the machine with the same architecture) as much as I can before. What are the minimal requirements for an usable Erlang environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the different erlware tools. Using the latest Sinan, you can even create a standalone release with the erts bundled.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I should have read it before ... (from INSTALL.md)

```
 *   Install using the `release` target. Instead of doing `make install` you
  can create the installation in whatever directory you like using the
  `release` target and run the `Install` script yourself. `RELEASE_ROOT`
  is used for specifying the directory where the installation should be
  created. This is what by default ends up under `/usr/local/lib/erlang`
  if you do the install using `make install`. All installation paths
  provided in the `configure` phase are ignored, as well as `DESTDIR`,
  and `INSTALL_PREFIX`. If you want links from a specific `bin` directory
  to the installation you have to set those up yourself. An example where
  Erlang/OTP should be located at `/home/me/OTP`:

      $ ./configure
      $ make
      $ make RELEASE_ROOT=/home/me/OTP release
      $ cd /home/me/OTP
      $ ./Install -minimal /home/me/OTP
      $ mkdir -p /home/me/bin
      $ cd /home/me/bin
      $ ln -s /home/me/OTP/bin/erl erl
      $ ln -s /home/me/OTP/bin/erlc erlc
      $ ln -s /home/me/OTP/bin/escript escript
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Wing3D](http://www.wings3d.com/) for example.

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is another example. (Credit to [tbikeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205948/tbikeev).)